# Questions about computation of Friedman's H-statistic

Tags: machine-learning, interaction, partial-dependency-plots

## Background

Christoph Molnar's [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/interaction.html) book introduces estimation of machine learning model interactions by the decomposition of partial dependences:

> If two features do not interact, we can compose the partial dependence function as follows: $$ PD_{jk}(x_j, x_k) = PD_j(x_j) + PD_k(x_k)$$. Likewise, if a feature has no interaction with any of the other features, we can express the prediction function $\hat{f}(x)$ as a sum of partial dependence functions, where the first summand depends only on $j$ and the second on all other features of $j$: $$\hat{f}(x) = PD_j(x_j) + PD_{-j}(x_{-j})$$

## Question 1

What is the computation of the second term in the second equation above, $PD_{-j}(x_{-j})$? Is it computed using predictions averaged over the grid values of $x_j$?

## Question 2

In the same chapter, it is claimed that computing j-vs-all interaction H-statistic requires, at the most, $3n^2$ calls to `predict`. Shouldn't this depend on `grid.size`, i.e., the resolution over which the partial dependences are evaluated? For example, I would expect that a univariate partial dependence requires `grid.size` $\times  n$ calls to predict. Extending this to a two-way partial dependence $PD(x, y)$, in the worst case it would be `grid.size` $\times n^2$. Where is Molnar's calculation coming from?